# OpenGL transparent texture clips previous one

Tags: opengl, transparency, textures

I tried to write text using open-gl, by using transparent PNGs containing digits, but when I write second letter it clips the first letter ( the transparent area of second clips the first letter)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [premultiplied alpha compositing](http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#%5b%5bPremultiplied%20alpha%5d%5d) man!